# Squid proxies very slow

Tags: squid

I have proxies set up via Squid. The proxies usually works great, but last couple months they've been very slow from time to time. It's not consistent.

I really don't know where to start.

Which steps should I follow to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem are the proxies. I tell you this because I used before Squid proxies and I had only problems with their proxies. Now, I use proxies from [Proxy-N-Vpn.com](http://www.Proxy-N-Vpn.com) and they are working perfect.

Comment: It must've been a temporary problem. I did nothing but it's solved.

Answer (score 1):

Check to see if the system is IO/CPU/Memory bound. If you're using it for caching then you may be running out of disk space.

If you don't see any issues around your system you can move on to better understanding

1. Understand the types of ACL's you are using http://www.eu.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/acl/. Note that there are fast and slow ACL's.
2. Learn how to utilize the debug sections. Setting the appropriate debug levels on possible pain points could reveal problems:
   http://wiki.squid-cache.org/KnowledgeBase/DebugSections

General tip on troubleshooting something like this is to try to understand the pattern. Is it slow during peek times? Is this a virtual machine that could be sharing resources with another vm that has high load? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

We had exhausted nofiles limits in our squid proxy server. Upon doubling the limits, it was super fast. We also added net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1 parameter in sysctl.conf